# converting varchar(50) to datetime and populating rest of the table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am working on  a data warehouse and in the data model theres a dimension table dim.date which needs to be populated from excel sheet.

this is table structure

```
CREATE TABLE timeme 
  ( 
     datekey             INT IDENTITY NOT NULL, 
     fulldate            VARCHAR(50), 
     englishdayname      VARCHAR(20), 
     englishmonthname    VARCHAR(20), 
     daynumberofthemonth INT, 
     daynumbarofyear     INT, 
     weeknumberofyear    INT, 
     calenderquater      INT, 
     calenderyear        INT 
  ) 

INSERT INTO timeme 
            (fulldate) 
VALUES     ('03-13-2013-02:41:38'), 
            ('03-13-2013-02:39:50'), 
            ('03-13-2013-02:53:15'), 
            ('03-13-2013-02:59:47')
```

This is what i tried

```
-- select * from timeme

--update timeme set fulldate= cast(left(fulldate, 10)+ ' ' +replace(substring(fulldate, 12, 12), '.', ':') as datetime)-- but it should be  2013-03-13 02:41:38.000

UPDATE timeme 
SET    englishdayname = Datename(dw, fulldate), 
       englishmonthname = Datename(mm, fulldate), 
       daynumberofthemonth = Datepart(d, fulldate) 

Update timeme 
SET daynumbarofyear -- this i didnt get rest how to populate
```

can somebody help me populating entire table

Comment: Doesn't Excel usually handle dates as dates?

Comment: may be..but the excel comes from third party vendor..when i try importing from excel to my sql server,,using `ssis tasks` it takes as varchar(10), and their comes the task of converting it to datetime!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```sql
UPDATE timeme
   SET fulldate = SUBSTRING(fulldate, 7, 4) + '-' + LEFT(fulldate, 5) + ' ' + RIGHT(fulldate, 8);

UPDATE timeme
   SET englishdayname      = DATENAME(dw, CAST(fulldate AS DATE)),
       englishmonthname    = DATENAME(mm, CAST(fulldate AS DATE)),
       daynumberofthemonth = DATEPART(dd, CAST(fulldate AS DATE)),
       daynumbarofyear     = DATEPART(dy, CAST(fulldate AS DATE)),
       weeknumberofyear    = DATEPART(ww, CAST(fulldate AS DATE)), -- or isoww instead of ww
       calenderquater      = DATEPART(qq, CAST(fulldate AS DATE)),
       calenderyear        = DATEPART(yy, CAST(fulldate AS DATE));
```

Outcome:

```
| DATEKEY |            FULLDATE | ENGLISHDAYNAME | ENGLISHMONTHNAME | DAYNUMBEROFTHEMONTH | DAYNUMBAROFYEAR | WEEKNUMBEROFYEAR | CALENDERQUATER | CALENDERYEAR |
|---------|---------------------|----------------|------------------|---------------------|-----------------|------------------|----------------|--------------|
|       1 | 2013-03-13 02:41:38 |      Wednesday |            March |                  13 |              72 |               11 |              1 |         2013 |
|       2 | 2013-03-13 02:39:50 |      Wednesday |            March |                  13 |              72 |               11 |              1 |         2013 |
|       3 | 2013-03-13 02:53:15 |      Wednesday |            March |                  13 |              72 |               11 |              1 |         2013 |
|       4 | 2013-03-13 02:59:47 |      Wednesday |            March |                  13 |              72 |               11 |              1 |         2013 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f88ca/1)** demo